# How to load a pickle file within Julia

Tags: julia, pickle

I have a pickle file that is written by using python (By using cPickle). I need to use it inside julia. I guess I can use PyCall for that purpose.Here is what I've done so far:

```
julia> using PyCall
julia> @pyimport cPickle as pickle
julia> f=open("mypicklefile.picle","r")
julia>  PyTextIO(f)[:seek](0) #if I don't do this, I got error. 
julia> trn,tst= pickle.load(PyTextIO(f))
```

Here,I have two questions. As far as I know, unlike Julia, python(numpy) is rowmajor. So, what should I do to read the content of file in a correct way? I guess somehow I have to tell the PyCall it is written in rowmajor order. 
My second question is about performance. The pickle file is about 4.5GB. When I read it inside python, it is completed in a minute whereas in julia it takes at least 15 minutes. Am I doing something wrong ? Since the file is not created by me, I cannot use another format such as hdf5 or jld.

Comment: Why don't you use Python to write it out in a more useful format, eg hdf5?  The timing difference is possibly due to converting the resulting python object to Julia.

Comment: It might be an option but I have a very limited python experience so I prefer not to do it if possible

Comment: I was considering creating a julia package for loading pickles, after doing: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/127402/4397
but using PyCall is probably going to be faster as cPickle is pretty optimised.
It might be possible to use `ccall` to call the backing compiled code behind cPickle (IIRC it is a C extension to python? vs the pure python pickle).
Last time I had to do this I did not any issues using PyCall to call pickle. But that was back in Julia0.3 days, and I might have only been saving not loading.

Comment: Like @DavidP.Sanders suggest, why not load it in Julia using Python as a pickle file and save it (in Julia) in a more useful file format (like hdf5 or jld).
 A one-time 30 min wait may be OK

Comment: Good point @DanGetz.

Comment: @DanGetz Yes sure, I did it like you suggest. I misunderstood David's suggestion I guess.